# Turbolinks and initialization scripts

Tags: javascript, turbolinks, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to implement smooth-scroll script in my Turbolinks web app, I need to call a script before the closing body tag:

```
var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {header: '[data-scroll-header]'});
```

It works but only on the first visit. Turbolinks should evaluate every script inside the body but it can't initialize smooth-scroll. I had this problem with others similar scripts.

If I put `console.log('hello');` I can see it printed every time I visit that page, so Turbolinks works.

I tried to add an event listener in the head but with the same results:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:render", function(event) {
      var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {header: '[data-scroll-header]'});
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `SmoothScroll` library is already loaded before you initialize it?

Comment: Yes,   `<script src="/scripts/smooth-scroll/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is in the head.